# Group *ngFor values in a dropdown without optgroup

Tags: angular, typescript

How I can group *ngFor data without optGroup in the dropdown selection. below is my JSON file link
[JSON Data](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hthkaw)

**typescripCode**

```
   getProducts() {
      if (this.products.length < 1) {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(p => {
        this.masterProductAttributeItems = p.MasterProductAttributeItems;
      });
    }
```

**html code**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let thing of masterProductAttributeItems">
      <option value="{{ thing.MasterProductAttributeItemId }}">
        {{ thing.Name }}
      </option>
   </ng-container>
</select>
```

[Currently how it's shwoing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dad6d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving `Name` which is not unique for the JSON you provided.
Here all Name is given as 'Weight'. So I just changed this code

```
 <option value="{{ thing.MasterProductAttributeItemId }}">
        {{ thing.Name }}
 </option>
```

to

```
<select class="form-control input-sm">
<ng-container *ngFor="let thing of masterProductAttributeItems">

   <option value="{{ thing.MasterProductAttributeItemId }}">
   {{ thing.MasterProductAttributeItem }}
   </option>
</ng-container>
```

For further demo, Please refer to this link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xamcuh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html